# Intercambio de nodos lista enlazada simple

Tags: java, lista, nodos

Hice este método. Busca un elemento y si se encuentra, lo pone al principio de la lista. Pero a la hora de intercambiar los lugares no lo hace. No sé si el enlace de punteros.

La clase nodo que utilizo:

```
public class Nodo{
    private int info;
    private Nodo sig;
    
    public Nodo(int valor){
        this.info=valor;
        this.sig=null;
    }

    void setInfo(int info){
        this.info=info;
    }

    void setSig(Nodo dir){
        this.sig=dir;
    }

    int getInfo(){
        return this.info;
    }

    Nodo getSig(){
        return this.sig;
    }
}
```

Y este es el método:

```
boolean Ordenar(int x){
    boolean enc=false;
    Nodo puntero= lista;
    Nodo q=null;
    while(puntero!=null && !enc){
        if(puntero.getInfo()==x){
            enc=true;
            q=puntero;
            puntero.setSig(q.getSig());
            lista.setSig(puntero);
        } else {
            puntero=puntero.getSig();
        }
    }
    return enc;
}
```

Usando esta lista: 5-4-3-12 debería quedar así si se desea poner al principio el número 3: 3-5-4-12

Comment: Qué es `p`? Lo usas en la función de ordenar pero no está definido.

Comment: Ahí lo actualicé, p viene siendo puntero

Comment: Si a `q` le asignas `puntero`, y luego a `puntero` le asignas lo que tenga `q` que es igual a `puntero`, no estás haciendo realmente nada. Esto está claro que no es lo que quieres hacer.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes 2 posibles escenarios:

- el elemento que buscas es el primero posición 0de la lista y por tanto no hay que hacer nada.
- El elemento está en la posición N, con N > 0: has de *recordar* cuál es el elemento previo para que apunte al siguiente.

Puesto que tu clase Nodo no apunta al elemento previo, ningún nodo sabe si es el primero de la lista o no, así que tendremos que asumir que si llamas al método `ordenar` de una instancia, ésta es la primera de la lista.

Además, tendremos que devolver el que se convierta en primer nodo de la lista, ya que será la única manera de saber el nuevo orden:

```
Nodo ordenar(int x) {
    if (this.info == x) {
        return this;
    }
    Nodo prev = this;
    Nodo actual = this;
    while (actual.info == x) {
        prev = actual; //tenemos una variable auxiliar apuntando al nodo previo
        actual = actual.getSig();
        if (actual == null) {
            return this; //no hay nada que ordenar
        }
    }
    prev.setSig(actual.getSig()); // "saltamos" al actual
    actual.setSig(this); // actual toma como siguiente nodo al que era el primero
    return actual;
}
```

Comment: No entiendo la comparación de x == 0. OP usa el valor contenido en el nodo, info, para determinar si es el que tiene que poner en primer lugar. Una RuntimeException me parece excesivo si se introduce un valor a buscar que no se encuentra en la lista. Lo de tener en cuenta el nodo previo sí me parece necesario.

Comment: Tienes rázón, pensé que X era la posición y no el valor del nodo... voy a arreglarlo